# Nesting a table with POJO data sources in BIRT

Tags: birt

I have a POJO data source that has several output columns, one of which is a Java Object (ArrayList). I can access this in my table but want I want to do is have a nested table that displays information from this Java Object (it is a list of objects). Something like a purchase order form that has purchased items in a table... Trying to figure out how to get started on this.

Comment: Using the same POJO Data source, you could create another Data Set having 2 columns : purchased order and purchased items. (You need to add extra java classes to do the mapping between two columns and re jar the files).
Later you can join this with the data set created earlier on purchased order.

Comment: Now I do have two data Sets, both POJO and in the open method they query two different web services. Once gets the PO form and the other gets just the items. That works but I have to do two web service calls. I was not sure if there is a way for one Data Set to get access to the variable that holds the returned data in the other Data Set? Trying to do this so there is just one web service call.

Comment: Try adding a List first and inside the list you can add the Table. Both List and Table can make use of the same Data Set. Group the List based on Purchased Order. Once you add a table you will get filter and other options to get to the desired output format. Let us know if this works!

Comment: Sanjay, thanks, not quite sure how to do that. I would think I would want the outer List to bind to the list of items and expose the Java object as a variable to the inner table. In the table I could then use that variable to get each member of the object. But, I can't figure out how to do that....